# Bitwise comparison in PHP

Tags: php, math, bit-manipulation, linden-scripting-language

I confess I don't really know what I'm doing! I'm pulling some data from SecondLife and parsing it in PHP. The data is an integer from [llGetRegionFlags](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlGetRegionFlags) which, in my case, returns 1048592

Now I need to do a bitwise comparison in PHP to figure out which flags are true/false. For example 0x00000040 is used for the "block terraform" flag.

The notations are in hex for each flag, and I have an integer to test against, and the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) suggests integers and shows examples in binary.

So my question really is, given an integer and some hex flags, how do I go about doing the bitwise comparison in PHP? Brainfried! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a particular bit is turned on, use the & (AND) operator:

```
if ($data & 0x00000040) {
    // block terraform flag is true
}
```

If the bit is turned on, the AND operator will return a positive number. If it is turned off, then the AND operator will result in a zero.

Comment: Aha thank you! I didn't realise I could compare a hex value against an integer, or how to use hex notation in PHP. Simple when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

Use a single AND `&` / OR `|`

```
if ($value1 & $value2) { }
```

The PHP Manual explains more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Thanks mcryan, sorry James pipped you to the post! I did try the manual but didn't realise I could compare hex against an integer etc

Answer (score 0):

You could define the bits required, and check against them to make it look clean. ie

```
define('BLOCK_TERAFORM', 0x00000040);

....

if($data & BLOCK_TERAFORM) {
  ... do something ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks hexblot great idea, keeps it clean

Answer (score 0):

Usually the bitflags are checked with a piece of code like this:

```
$blockTerraformFlag = 0x00000040;
$isBlockTerraform = (($RegionFlags & $blockTerraformFlag) == $blockTerraformFlag);
```